# If and elif are not printing

Tags: python, printing, if-statement

```
print'Personal information, journal and more to come'
x = raw_input()
if x ==("Personal Information"): # wont print 
 print' Edward , Height: 5,10 , EYES: brown , STATE: IL TOWN:  , SS:'
elif x ==("Journal"):  # wont print 
 read = open('C:\\python\\foo.txt' , 'r')
 name = read.readline()
 print (name)
```

I start the program and `"Personal information, journal and more to come"` shows but when I type either `Personal information` or `journal neither` of them print the result and I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 4):

> when i type either Personal information or journal

Well, yeah. It isn't expecting either of those; your case is wrong.

To perform a case-insensitive comparison, convert both to the same case first.

```
if foo.lower() == bar.lower():
```

Comment: ehhh i think i need a better explaination im a beginner what would that look like in the actual script? are you trying to make the text in my file lowercase? and whats bar

Comment: What are these mysterious objects `foo` and `bar`??? O.o @EdwardLaPiere: foo and bar are just example variables. You would replace them with whatever objects you're actually interested in comparing.

Comment: also one more question how do i loop the code so i can keep on entering both options with out getting an error saying somethings not defined?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Are you writing "Personal Information" with a capital I?

```
print'Personal information, journal and more to come'
x = raw_input()
if x == ("Personal Information"): # wont print
    print' Edward , Height: 5,10 , EYES: brown , STATE: IL TOWN:  , SS:'
elif x ==("Journal"):  # wont print
    read = open('C:\\python\\foo.txt' , 'r')
    name = read.readline()
    print (name)
```

output:

```
[00:20: ~$] python py
Personal information, journal and more to come
Journal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py", line 8, in <module>
    read = open('C:\\python\\foo.txt' , 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\python\\foo.txt'
[00:20: ~$] python py
Personal information, journal and more to come
Personal Information
 Edward , Height: 5,10 , EYES: brown , STATE: IL TOWN:  , SS:
[00:20: ~$]
```

Perhaps it's the formatting? I'm using 4 white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You are typing in Personal information, when the if statement is expecting Personal Information (with a capital I for information).

What you can do (what Ignacio above is eluding to) is do:

```
if x.lower() == ("Personal Information").lower():
```

instead of:

```
if x == ("Personal Information"):
```

then any case, "Personal information", "personal information", "personAL infoRmation", and so on, will match and go into the if statement.  The reason this works is because when this executes, it will take the value of x, and make it a lowercase string, and the string "Personal information" and make it a lowercase string, so now no matter what the case originally was, they both will be lowercase when comparing.

foo and bar are examples, common programming nomenclature in programming.  It is just an example of any variable, x, y, z, etc, could have been used just as easily, but foo and bar are just common variables to refer to.